# Change the right BarButtonItem of a manually added UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I have a `UINavigationBar`that I have manually dragged and added to a ViewController in my storyboard. Within that NavigationBar I have dragged and added a "UIBarButtonItem" styled as the default "Add" image.

The view is pushed modally, so it does not have a NavigationBar that is automatically pushed with it.

Both the navBar and the BarButton are connected to my viewcontroller and the storyboard like so

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *RibbonDetailNavBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *addRemoveButton;
```

I try to change the button image to another default, the Trash icon, in `viewDidLoad` like so

```
if (alreadyAdded)
{
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash];
}
```

Which had no effect.

I have also tried this:

```
if (alreadyAdded)
{
    _addRemoveButton = nil;
}
```

Which also had no effect

and also this:

```
if (alreadyAdded)
{
    _addRemoveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:nil style:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:nil action:nil];
}
```

which also had no effect.

How do I set this button to the trash icon?

Comment: Did you check (in `viewDidLoad`) in the debugger that the button item you're trying to set exists and is indeed Add style?

Comment: Yes. It loads and appears correctly in the app. It calls the appropriate IBAction connected to it on TouchUpInside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash` cannot be retrieved by `style` property. style is of type UIBarButtonItemStyle which can be `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`, `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`

Look into the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem)

Use this code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *RibbonDetailNavBar;
// No need to create rightBarButtonItem IBOutlet.
if (alreadyAdded)
{
    self.RibbonDetailNavBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target: nil action: nil];
}
else {
    self.RibbonDetailNavBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target: nil action: nil];
}
```

Hope it helps you. Happy coding! :)